# How to write this SQL in Pandas?

Tags: sql, pandas, python-3.6

I have this SQL code and I want to write in in Pandas. Every example I saw uses groupby and order by outside of the window function and that is not what I want. I don't want my data to look grouped, instead I just need a cumulative sum of my new column (reg_sum) ordered by hour for each article_id.

```
SELECT
*,
SUM(registrations) OVER(PARTITION BY article_id ORDER BY time) AS 
cumulative_regs
FROM table
```

Data example of what I need to get (reg_sum column):

```
article_id  time    registrations   reg_sum
      A      7          6              6
      A      9          5              11
      B      10         1              1
      C      10         2              2
      C      11         4              6
```

If anyone can say what is the equivalent of this in Pandas, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to help if you don't include some data and the desired output. We don't all speak SQL fluently.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `cumsum`, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate data
df = pd.DataFrame({'article_id': np.array(['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']), 
                   'time': np.array([7, 9, 10, 10, 11]), 
                   'registrations': np.array([6, 5, 1, 2, 4])})

# compute cumulative sum of registrations sorted by time and grouped by article_id
df['reg_sum'] = df.sort_values('time').groupby('article_id').registrations.cumsum()
```

Output:

```
  article_id  time  registrations  reg_sum
0          A     7              6        6
1          A     9              5       11
2          B    10              1        1
3          C    10              2        2
4          C    11              4        6
```